# How many ways to get this poker hand?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a standard deck of cards (52 cards), how many ways a player can be dealt a hand (5 cards) that contains at least one 7 but no 9 ?

Since we have no 9, and we have four 9's in the 52 cards, so are choosing from 48 cards instead of 52 cards.

Now since we need at least one 7, then we can subtract the combinations that have no 7 from all different combinations that we can from the 48 cards.

Which is $${48 \choose 5} - {44 \choose 5}$$

we have four 7's and so that's why I have ${44 \choose 5}$ which represents the combinations that don't contain any 7.

Is this correct or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   Well reasoned.   That is the count of selecting 5 cards from 48 that includes some of a certain 4 among them.